# Lua Pattern Matching, get character before match

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

Currently I have code that looks like this:

```
somestring = "param=valueZ&456"
local stringToPrint = (somestring):gsub("(param=)[^&]+", "%1hello", 1)
```

StringToPrint will look like this:

```
param=hello&456
```

I have replaced all of the characters before the `&` with the string "hello". This is where my question becomes a little strange and specific.

I want my string to appear as: `param=helloZ&456`. In other words, I want to preserve the character right before the `&` when replacing the string `valueZ` with `hello` to make it `helloZ` instead. How can this be done?

Comment: What is the expected output for `"param=valueZ&param=456"`? Or this can't happen? Try `somestring:gsub("(param=)[^&]+([^&])", "%1hello%2", 1)`, see http://ideone.com/pHRgAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
somestring:gsub("param=[^&]*([^&])", "param=hello%1", 1)
```

See the [Lua demo](http://ideone.com/tUFPRa)

Here, the pattern matches:

- `param=` - literal substring `param=`
- `[^&]*` - 0 or more chars other than `&` as many as possible
- `([^&])` - Group 1   capturing a symbol other than `&` (here, backtracking will occur, as the previous pattern grabs all such chars other than `&` and then the engine will take a step back and place the last char from that chunk into Group 1).

Comment: Suppose if it was: `param=a&xyz`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your demo works but the suggestion has `()` around param so that it doesnt work

Comment: @Rochet2: I forgot to remove the redundant group. Removed now. I think if you match a literal string, you do not need to add capturing overhead.

Comment: Both solutions work for this case, but as suggested by @hjpotter92 it will not work for `param=a&xyz` (if `valueZ` is replaced by some value with one or two characters)

Comment: @kshah: I actually see the difference between `param=a&xyz` (Harry Potter's) and your `param=valueZ&456` in just the number of characters before the `&`. If you need to get `param=helloa&xyz` from the first, you need to replace `+` with `*` in my pattern: [`"param=[^&]*([^&])"`](http://ideone.com/tUFPRa).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably other ways to do this, but here is one:

```
somestring = "param=valueZ&456"
local stringToPrint = (somestring):gsub("(param=).-([^&]&)", "%1hello%2", 1)
print(stringToPrint)
```

The thing here is that I match the shortest string that ends with a character that is not & and a character that is &. Then I add the two ending characters to the replaced part.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, how might you do this if we wanted to replace everything before the end of the string (e.g. `param=valueZ` to `param=helloZ`) rather than before the first `&` character

Comment: @kshah You mean `"(param=).+(.)"`?

Comment: Both solutions work for this case, but as suggested by @hjpotter92 it will not work for `param=a&xyz` (if `valueZ` is replaced by some value with one or two characters)